# How layout images, so screen rotation has no effect

Tags: android, image, layout

I have some `ImageButton` , that I want to represent user friendly, like here: [link to image](https://lh3.ggpht.com/yQ20qLPUN4L3O47ShR0hKIzm8YjLpadu5DhIwdxQNSIkfgqWIXcQRmiXXCPod0nIOeo=h900-rw)
.I can't use GridLayout because it supports only sandwich. Main idea is to not have empty space when user rotates screen. Thank you for any suggestions :)

I am right now trying different layouts, like table, relative etc, and trying to find which one would fit my needs, so when user rotates phone there would not be extra white space
XML:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
     >




    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/min"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:contentDescription="min.lt_foto"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/min_lt_logo"
        android:onClick="IB_min"
        />

       <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/VersliLietuva"
           android:layout_width="50dp"
           android:layout_height="50dp"

           android:contentDescription="VersliLietuva"
           android:background="@drawable/versli_lietuva" 
           android:layout_margin="10dp"
           android:onClick="IB_VersliLietuva"
           />

        <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/ezys"
           android:layout_width="50dp"
           android:layout_height="50dp"

           android:contentDescription="ezys"
           android:background="@drawable/ezys" 
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
           android:onClick="IB_ezys"
           />

          <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/pienas"
           android:layout_width="50dp"
           android:layout_height="50dp"

           android:contentDescription="pienas"
           android:background="@drawable/pienas" 
         android:layout_margin="10dp"
           android:onClick="IB_pienas"
           />


</ScrollView>
```

Comment: [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/GridLayout.html) is available for usage via the support v7 library

Comment: is those items static???

Comment: Provide code and/or xml layouts.

Comment: only images that I want to represent and let people to click on them, grid View does the work, but maybe there is some other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html, there's everything you need to know about grid views (supported starting from API Level 1).

Basically you have to implement your adapter in order to specify the content of each element of the grid. Of course, clicks on items are supported through `setOnItemClickListener`.

Comment: So if I want to use something similar to my link(it's quiz game), only way is to use grid views?

Comment: This is not the only way but it's practical and quicker (possibly with better performances) than providing your custom layout. Please also consider the GridLayout is provided by the support v7 library, so it really depends on your requirements about the minimum version you have to support. I suggest you to read both documentation and experiment a bit before taking your decision.